# Record video inside of iOS app, immediately play and loop

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking for a way for my users to take a video (defaulting to front facing camera, but with the ability to switch) lasting 2 seconds, display that video immediately and have it loop indefinitely (no controls displayed).  Essentially mimicking a 2 second gif.  I would like to do this in app so they can see the video before posting, and potentially retake.  Any ideas?  I've found some functionality here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMovieControlStyle  but it doesn't seem to address the entire problem set.

Comment: Can you make your question more specific? *How do I record video?* is too broad to be a useful question.

Comment: Caleb, where did you read "How do I record video?" in my question above?  It's very specific about what I would like to do.

Comment: There are several different frameworks for recording video in iOS, all of which provide control over which camera to use, video duration, etc. Likewise for playback. What you need to know to fulfill your list of specific requirements isn't clear, and "Any ideas?" is not a sufficiently detailed question.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this guide from Apple:

[Using Video](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingVideo/UsingVideo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH3-SW1)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am new to SO, are there some guidelines that say what should be  a comment and what should be an answer?

Comment: Well, in this case, the criteria is basically,"does it actually answer the question, or just give more information that leads the OP to their own answer.  Also of note in this case, link only answers are frowned upon since the original link may go away at any time.  Better is to at least summarize the salient points of the answer and include the link as a 'for more information see...'